Android Studio Error: Valid XML document must have a root tag also Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler
While running my android project, I fail to run it having following 2 errors in my Build Output tab:
First section of errors is:


Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

>
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnableResource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file
>
Exception is:org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)at    org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:134)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:78)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnableat org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:283)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:130)at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:336)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:319)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:324)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:126)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:92)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:78)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:66)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:256)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:233)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:216)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:199)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:78)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:179)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:77)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:38)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:108)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:55)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.lambda$execute$2(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:66)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:66)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:38)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:293)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:134)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:78)at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)Caused by: com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompilationException: Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\Ranger\Desktop\Bible App\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5bcf3a3e.. Check logs for more details.at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler.compileResource(ResourceCompiler.kt:129)at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable$Companion.compileSingleResource(ResourceCompilerRunnable.kt:34)at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable.run(ResourceCompilerRunnable.kt:15)at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:78)at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:170)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:133)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)... 2 moreCaused by: com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompilationException: Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\Ranger\Desktop\Bible App\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xmlat com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler.compileTable(ResourceCompiler.kt:192)at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler.access$compileTable(ResourceCompiler.kt:1)at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler$getCompileMethod$1.invoke(ResourceCompiler.kt:138)at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler$getCompileMethod$1.invoke(ResourceCompiler.kt:138)at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler.compileResource(ResourceCompiler.kt:123)... 32 moreCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5bcf3a3e.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5ff0b59f.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1af23005.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@99e6a12.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@2ba2afd5.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3b89e8f8.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@659baec9.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@6cbc4654.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@24deab0a.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@50e44941.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@68315872.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@66b12dc6.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@37e64ce1.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@45baa51d.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@272a8710.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@489a512e.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4d1e8d98.at com.android.aaptcompiler.TableExtractor.extractResourceValues(TableExtractor.kt:270)at com.android.aaptcompiler.TableExtractor.extract(TableExtractor.kt:181)at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler.compileTable(ResourceCompiler.kt:188)... 36 more

BUILD FAILED in 2s24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date



Second section of errors is:


Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5bcf3a3e.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5ff0b59f.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1af23005.,Can not extract
resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@99e6a12.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@2ba2afd5.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@7124ab73.,Can not extract resource from
com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@7addcf4a.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@69e4f9.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3e0b2f26.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@6a2064a7.,Can
not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@7e935136.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@31123c31.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5607472a.,Can not extract
resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3f6b0411.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5b95e82b.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@7b46a4dc.,Can not extract resource from
com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@17948289.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@703857e6.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4183d7a.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4a360961.,Can
not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@79855a64.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4bb0a5d5.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@e06b234.,Can not extract
resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@7401cf94.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@2784ed0a.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@69d46a22.,Can not extract resource from
com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5278e23e.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@287ffa8a.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@2813ae32.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@625c4468.,Can
not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@77a0330f.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@20dc2cdb.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@158b74cc.,Can not extract
resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@15740d11.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@63ba6cfb.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@22c12ea3.,Can not extract resource from
com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@6ca20323.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@598b8723.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@69e6f55d.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@42f97af4.,Can
not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3ebec293.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3b89e8f8.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@659baec9.,Can not extract
resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@6cbc4654.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@24deab0a.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@50e44941.,Can not extract resource from
com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@68315872.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@66b12dc6.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@37e64ce1.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@45baa51d.,Can
not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@272a8710.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@489a512e.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4d1e8d98.



I'm also getting some other weird errors of Valid XML document must have a root tag
Last Action: I know it's not wrong though because it's only having problems with 5 of the values when I used the same copy paste of those values in the other 22 values and there's no errors. I don't know what else to do.

Whatever formatting you did for this post has made it unreadable.  Just use a code block rather than blockquotes for the error please.

But all this means is you have some badly formed resource xml files.  We can't help more without the code of that file(s).

It's a consistent error of: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@37eb4e77
